# NSMutableArray count always returns (null)

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

Can anyone tell me why [NSMutableArray count] is always returning (null) in the debug window? It is initialized, the matching letters are registering, but it still does not return anything but null.

```
@implementation NSString (Word)
-(NSMutableArray *)placeOfLetter: (char)letterAsked;{

    NSMutableArray *matchingLetters;
    matchingLetters=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    int len=(int)[self length];
    NSLog(@"length of word: %i, letterAsked=%c",len,letterAsked);
    NSUInteger counter=[matchingLetters count];

    for (NSUInteger x=0; x<[self length]; x++) {
        if ([self characterAtIndex:x]==letterAsked){
            NSNumber *foundPosition = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:x];
            [matchingLetters addObject:foundPosition];
            NSLog(@"found at place : %@",foundPosition);
            NSLog(@"counter: %@",counter);
        }
    }
    if ([matchingLetters count]<=0){
         NSLog(@"counter: %@",counter);
         NSLog(@"no letters ");
        return nil;
    }else{
        return matchingLetters;
    }
}
```

Comment: This line is incorrent: NSLog(@"counter: %@",counter);. Counter is not an object, so it's incorrect to use %@.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the `counter` variable? You are assigning the count of `matchingLetters` to this variable **before** adding any elements, so at this point it is of course being assigned 0.

When you later `NSLog()` the value of `counter`, it will still be 0. There is no automatic update mechanism that would magically update counter with the new count of `matchingLetters` once you've added elements to this array. And it displays as (null) because you're using `%@` instead of `%qu`.

If that's not what you're referring to, are you perhaps referring to breaking your application in the debugger and then entering `p -[matchingLetters count]`? Or are you referring to part of the variables display on the left side of the debugging console (if so, a screenshot of what you're seeing might be helpful)?

Comment: It was the first one. Stupid mistake on my part

Answer (score 1):

> NSLog(@"counter: %@",counter);

You're using the `%@` format specifier here, which means that `NSLog` expects an object pointer. But you're passing in a `NSUInteger`, which is just a number.

If you're getting "(null)" here, it's lucky for you that the array doesn't have any objects in it. If the array had some objects, you'd get a number like `7` back, and interpreting that as a pointer to an object is likely to cause a crash.

The fix is to simply use the right format specifier (`%u`) instead:

```
NSLog(@"counter: %u",counter);
```